# How to run JDBC code from terminal?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, terminal

I have compiled my code using `-cp <mysql-connector-java jar file>`. There were no errors during the compilation. All the class files were created
 To run the code, I went to one directory higher and did `java packagename.MyPgm`. 
 However, when i run this is the error that pops up:

```
Error in line no: -1
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?user=root&password=passwd
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:640)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:222)
    at javaapplication2.HttpHeaderParser.main(HttpHeaderParser.java:69)
```

> import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
>   
> import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
>   
> import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
>   
> import java.io.*;
>   
> import java.sql.DriverManager;
>   
> import java.sql.SQLException;
>   
> import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HttpHeaderParser {

```
static Connection connect = null;
static Statement statement = null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("http_headers.txt")));   
        FirstLine firstObj = null;
        SecondLine secondObj;
        OtherFields otherObj;
        connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"+"user=root&password=sicily");  //this will connect to the database
        statement = (Statement) connect.createStatement();
```

I've got some java String operations here. And then the catch statement.

```
catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in line no: "+lineCount);                 //displays the line number of the input file where the program stopped
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The program is syntactically correct. The problem arises during run-time. The DriverManager is not able to get or find the instance during run time.

Comment: Is this the complete stack trace that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, this is all i'm getting.

Comment: Edit your question by including the code that you used.

Comment: There you go. Please have a look.

Comment: In the getConnection method, what exactly are u doing? `"jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"+"user=root&password=sicily"` check the syntaxes properly from [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

Comment: try passing the values seperately like `"jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback","root","sicily"`

Answer (score 1):

You still need to run the code with classpath argument.

So should be:

```
java packagename.MyPgm -cp <mysql-connector-java jar file>
```

Try it out and let/

EDIT:

This line is supposed to be added, before creating the connection.

sample:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username",  "password");
conn.close();
```

EDIT 2:

Fixing only certain part of code:

```
OtherFields otherObj;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"+"user=root&password=sicily");  //this will connect to the database
statement = (Statement) connect.createStatement();
```

Once this is done, compile with,

```
javac HttpHeaderParser.java -cp <mysql jar file>
```

When compilation is successful, you need to run the same.

```
java HttpHeaderParser -cp <mysql jar file>
```

But remember the place where you are writing the JDBC code does not look like a right place.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
 at javaapplication2.HttpHeaderParser.main(HttpHeaderParser.java:69)

Comment: HttpHeaderParser is my main java program. and this is the new bunch of errors that have come up.
I just added the the first of the 4 lines you suggested. The remaining three were already there.

Comment: Now run with -cp argument as suggested in my answer.

Comment: I ran with -cp arguement and this error persists. I've included my code in the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need a file something like 
        `"mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar"`
        in your `classpath`, and the appropriate references to it in your program

It appears you are replacing the `classpath` to reference only the one file,
        You probably need at least "." also.

Comment: If the jar file wasn't there as you mentioned, it would generate an compile time error as ClassNotFound.

Comment: I have this same jar file. And used it in compiling. There were no errors during compilation.

Comment: @DhruvaJain During compilation you usually don't need the classes of a specific JDBC driver, at runtime you do need it.

Comment: @Maximin The OP was not complaining about the compile, rather the run-time. I was answering about the run-time.